# Symfony 3/4/9 routing is not working. I have created controller using cmd(php bin/console make:controller)

Tags: symfony

Route is not working for new controller. I have created new controller. Check the following screen shot.

http://prntscr.com/jca5xz

When i tying following url http://localhost/my-project/user. Then nothing is coming out.

Comment: I am using Symfony version 3.4.9

Answer (score 0):

After spending whole day, I have found that there was issue in .htaccess.  If anyone is facing same issue then check the htaccess for same.

RewriteEngine On

```
# Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```